# How can I configure Ansible playbook to ignore certain error codes?

Tags: ansible

I have a task to configure the following Ansible playbook to ignore error code 422 (which should happen when it looks for a volume that is detached from the server).
Furthermore, I currently see that this situation can also display error code 400, so, I may also have to exclude this.

```yaml
    # ---
#   # This script will print the received parameters only
 - hosts: localhost
   connection: local

#   # Required parameters
#   # for testing locally
   vars:
     server_id: xxx
     backup_properties:
       name: xxx
       retention_period: x
       volume_ids:
       - xxx

   gather_facts: no

   tasks:

    # Get moss_url variable
    - include_tasks: ../vault_get_moss_environment.yml   

    # Request the backup from the endpoint
    - name: Call MOS Windows Service Endpoint
      uri:
        url: "{{ moss_url }}/v1/service-instances/{{ server_id }}/backups"
        method: POST
        return_content: yes
        status_code: 202
        headers:
            Content-Type: "application/json"
            Authorization: "Bearer {{ getToken.json.access_token }}"
        body_format: json
        body: {
              "name": "{{ backup_properties.name | default('Backup Before Update') }}",
              "volumeIds": "{{ backup_properties.volume_ids | default(omit) }}",
              "retentionPeriod": "{{ backup_properties.retention_period | default(14) }}" 
        }
      register: trigger_backup_response 
      no_log: false
      ignore_errors: yes
    
    - fail:
       msg: "Error code: {% if trigger_backup_response.msg %}{{ trigger_backup_response.msg }}{% else %}{{ trigger_backup_response }}{% endif %}"
      when: trigger_backup_response.failed | default(false) and trigger_backup_response.json.status != "NOT_FOUND" # .failed is defined only when it fails

    - name: Delete server's backup schedules if server is not found in Openstack
      include_tasks: ../MOSS/call_moss_delete_backup_schedules.yml
      vars:
        id: "{{ server_id }}"
      when: trigger_backup_response.status == 404 and trigger_backup_response.json.status == "NOT_FOUND"

    - name: Get the id from the content
      debug: 
        msg: "Started backup job with id: {{ trigger_backup_response.json.id }} for server with id: {{ server_id }}"
      when: trigger_backup_response.status == 202

    - name: Set backup_job_id as a fact 
      set_fact: 
        backup_job_id="{{ trigger_backup_response.json.id }}"
      when: trigger_backup_response.status == 202
    
    ###### Please do not delete this debug as it is used by MOSS #####
    - debug:
        msg: "backup_job_id={{ backup_job_id }}"
      when: trigger_backup_response.status == 202
```

I am aware that I probably have to use `ignore_erros` in some context, but, am not able to locate any way to exclude errors specifically by their code.

So, overall the question is how can I make this playbook ignore specifically errors 422 and 400 without sending any alerts or performing any actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a better mechanism than `ignore_errors` in this case, it is [`failed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure).
With it, you can fine grain the failure of a task to exactly what you want.

In your case it would be something like:

```yaml
- name: Call MOS Windows Service Endpoint
  uri:
    url: https://example.org/api
  ## reduced the uri for brevity
  register: trigger_backup_response
  failed_when: trigger_backup_response.status not in [202, 400, 422]
```

This will cause the codes `202`, `400` and `422` to have a successful task, all other status code would, then, fail.

Next to this, in order to handle the tasks based on the return of that API call, you can either use a [`block`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html):

```yaml
- block:
    - debug:
        msg: First task upon receiving a return form the API

    - debug:
        msg: Second task upon receiving a return form the API

    - debug:
        msg: Third task upon receiving a return form the API

  when: trigger_backup_response.status == 202
```

Or, stop the execution totally, with the help of the [`meta` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html).
The task here under will stop the play, on an host basis, if the the return code of the API is either `400` or `422`.

```yaml
- meta: end_host
  when: trigger_backup_response.status in [400, 422]
```

So, having a scenario like:

```yaml
- name: Call API
  uri:
    url: https://example.org/api
  register: trigger_backup_response
  failed_when: trigger_backup_response.status not in [202, 400, 422]

- name: End play for hosts with detached volumes
  meta: end_host
  when: trigger_backup_response.status in [400, 422]

## From now on, it is safe to assume
## we are only dealing with API answer status being 202
- name: Display volume IDs
  debug:
    var: backup_properties.volume_ids
```

Comment: Thanks! So this is successfully making it ignore the 422 error, we have meanwhile deployed a fix that eliminates the 400 error. However, now it throws a failure when it should be running normally with 202 and volume attached. I think it gets messed up with the trigger_backup_response and the fail condition.

Comment: If you removed the status 400, you should have `failed_when: trigger_backup_response.status not in [202, 422]`. Is that what you do have?

Comment: Yes, I tried both with just [422] and [202, 422]. Still giving some error that the trigger_backup_response gets messed up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So two things turned out to be the issue here:

1. I had forgotten initally to refresh my project in AWS.
2. The `failed_when` had to be used before `no_log: false` and `ignore_errors: yes` (the no_log part probably didn't matter too much, but the ignore_errors mechanism was apparently taking effect as it was before the condition of when not to fail).

Currently, the working code looks like this:

```
# ---
#   # This script will print the received parameters only
# - hosts: localhost
#   connection: local

#   # Required parameters
#   # for testing locally
#   vars:
#     server_id: xxx
#     backup_properties:
#       name: xxx
#       retention_period: x
#       volume_ids:
#       - xxx

#   # gather_facts: no

#   tasks:

    # Get moss_url variable
    - include_tasks: ../vault_get_moss_environment.yml   

    # Request the backup from the endpoint
    - name: Call MOS Windows Service Endpoint
      uri:
        url: "{{ moss_url }}/v1/service-instances/{{ server_id }}/backups"
        method: POST
        return_content: yes
        status_code: 202
        headers:
            Content-Type: "application/json"
            Authorization: "Bearer {{ getToken.json.access_token }}"
        body_format: json
        body: {
              "name": "{{ backup_properties.name | default('Backup Before Update') }}",
              "volumeIds": "{{ backup_properties.volume_ids | default(omit) }}",
              "retentionPeriod": "{{ backup_properties.retention_period | default(14) }}" 
        }
      register: trigger_backup_response
      failed_when: trigger_backup_response.status not in [202, 422] 
      no_log: false
      ignore_errors: yes
    
    - fail:
       msg: "Error code: {% if trigger_backup_response.msg %}{{ trigger_backup_response.msg }}{% else %}{{ trigger_backup_response }}{% endif %}"
      when: trigger_backup_response.failed | default(false) and trigger_backup_response.json.status != "NOT_FOUND" # .failed is defined only when it fails

    - name: Delete server's backup schedules if server is not found in Openstack
      include_tasks: ../MOSS/call_moss_delete_backup_schedules.yml
      vars:
        id: "{{ server_id }}"
      when: trigger_backup_response.status == 404 and trigger_backup_response.json.status == "NOT_FOUND"

    - name: Get the id from the content
      debug: 
        msg: "Started backup job with id: {{ trigger_backup_response.json.id }} for server with id: {{ server_id }}"
      when: trigger_backup_response.status == 202

    - name: Set backup_job_id as a fact 
      set_fact: 
        backup_job_id="{{ trigger_backup_response.json.id }}"
      when: trigger_backup_response.status == 202
    
    ###### Please do not delete this debug as it is used by MOSS #####
    - debug:
        msg: "backup_job_id={{ backup_job_id }}"
      when: trigger_backup_response.status == 202
```

With that said, the previous answer was completely valid, just needed some modifications in this specific case. So thanks a lot for the assistance! =)